# How to check if an activity has changed Android Studio

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, junit4

Im trying to write a junit test to see if clicking a button has changed the activity. I have the following start of a test, but how Can i check whether a new activity has begun?

```
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SignIn> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<SignIn>(SignIn.class);

    private SignIn mSignIn = null;

    @Test
    public void testInput() {
        assertNotNull(mSignIn.findViewById(R.id.signInButton)); 


        mSignIn.findViewById(R.id.signInButton).performClick(); 



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking whether the **new Activity** has begun or not, you should be adding a test to that Activity and checking whether **onCreateView**() has been called or not, or you may check whether the views(buttons, text view, edit texts), etc has been initialized or not, you if you passing some data, you may check that too.

And in the current Activity, you may check whether your intent value is null or not, also you may check whether **startActivity**() is called or not.

I hope this will help.